# LOOKUP function gives N/A answer in some selected list options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns in excel first one is normal text second one is the list where we can select different options and the third one is the **LOOKUP** function associated with the list so according to option I select it changes the value.

[image]

In the third column I first two-row is working properly but in the third one when I select the third option I got N/A answer I am not sure what is the problem because I provided the proper location.

Here is my [**EXCEL FILE**](https://gofile.io/?c=Gy8dJd)

here is my lookup command

```
=LOOKUP(B5,D33:D35,E33:E35)
```

Please help me if you need any information from my side please comment. Thank You

Comment: Yes, I also think I have a problem with my data because the first two are working fine. I will post the file for reference.

Comment: Does the target list spell Bachelor correctly which means your lookup won't find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LOOKUP** function does approximate match but judging from your file I think you want exact match. Please switch to **VLOOKUP** and your function should be something like the following in Cell `C5` which shall return `26`.

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,D33:E35,2,FALSE)
```

As explained in this article [Excel LOOKUP Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-lookup-function):

> When lookup_value is less than all (i.e. the first) value in lookup_vector, LOOKUP returns #N/A.

[image: Compare]

In the above example, `Bechalor Degree or Above` is actually less than `High School` which is the first value in your look up range so it explained why your command returned `#N/A`.

Another way to solve the issue is to sort your look up range alphabetically (by Column D) then your **LOOKUP** function will return the desired figure from Column E.

Comment: Thank you @Terry for the answer and it working but when I am trying the same for the location it is not working.

Comment: @ArpitPatel what's your formula for location? It should be something like this: `=VLOOKUP(B6,D39:E42,2,0)` or `=VLOOKUP(B6,D:E,2,0)` which is more universal in your excel file. Based on the nature of your data in Column D, I think you can use this formula in Cell `C1` `=VLOOKUP(B1,D:E,2,0)` and drag it down. It should return the exact match for each look up item, otherwise you will need to manually adjust the look up range for each look up item.